# How to use components from a form in another form in C# Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, visual-studio-2010, methods

So, I have a Form1 that contains a treeView1(made in designer view) and a Form3 which opens on a button click from Form1. In Form3, I want to be able to use treeView1 from Form1 in one or more methods and I don't know how to do this (make it recognise treeView1 from Form1). I'm pretty new to C# and VS2010.

The question is how to do it for the specific case I mentioned, and how to generaly be able to use components from a form in other forms.

Form1 code:

```
    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 f3 = new Form3();
        f3.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Form3 code:

```
          private void Add_Function()
          {
                // code...
                string node = Form1.treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
                // more code
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Send your **treeview** object of **FORM1** to **FORM3** through below code

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 f3 = new Form3();
    f3.TreeView1 =  treeView1;
    f3.ShowDialog();
}
```

//Create a treeview variable in **FORM3** which holds the properties of **FORM1** Treeview.

```
public class Form3 
{
  public TreeView TreeView1 = null;
}
```

//And finally call your local **treeview** for use

```
private void Add_Function()
{
  // code...
  string node = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
  // more code
 }
```

Comment: Well all variants work, thankyou all for your replies and time. Since I am a fan of simplicity, I will chose this one as the best answer BUT I tested each answer and each one is ok. Now this is the simplest but I wonder which practice is the best(most correct one, to say so) for working with components from other forms.

Answer (score 1):

Have your Form3 contain a reference to the Form1 instance, which you pass in through a `SetForm1Instance` method when you create it.

```
public class Form3 {
    Form1 form1;

    void SetForm1Instance(Form1 inst) { 
        form1 = inst;
    }

     private void Add_Function()
     {
          // code...
          string node = form1.TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
          // more code
     }  

    //remaining Form3 code
}
```

And in Form1, just pass `this` to that method.

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 f3 = new Form3();
    f3.SetForm1Instance(this);
    f3.ShowDialog();
}

public TreeView TreeView1 { get { return treeView1; } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass your `TreeView` control from Form1 to the constructor for Form3:

```
public class Form3 {
    TreeView _Form1TreeViewControl;

     public Form3(TreeView form1TreeViewControl) {
        InitializeComponent();
        _Form1TreeViewControl = form1TreeViewControl
     }

     private void Add_Function()
     {
          // code...
          string node = _Form1TreeViewControl.SelectedNode.Text;
          // more code
     }  

    //remaining Form3 code
}
```

Then, in Form1:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 f3 = new Form3(treeView1);
    f3.ShowDialog();
}
```